# JPanel z-ordering

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have one base `JPanel` on which I will place other `JPanel` items. I want to show one `JPanel` on top of the other `JPanel` item.

I tried with the code below, but it did not work.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelParent extends JFrame
{

    public JPanelParent() throws HeadlessException {
        JPanel nPanel = getNode(10,10,20,20, Color.red,1);
        JPanel nPanel2 = getNode(20,20,20,20, Color.yellow,2);
        JPanel nPanel3 = getNode(30,30,20,20, Color.green,3);
        add(nPanel);
        add(nPanel2);
        add(nPanel3);
    }

    public JPanel getNode(int i, int i1, int j, int j1, Color color, int zOrder){
        JPanel nodePanel = new JPanel();
        nodePanel.setBackground(color);
        nodePanel.setBounds(i,i1,j,j1);
        nodePanel.setOpaque(true);
        nodePanel.setLayout(null);
        return nodePanel;
    }


    public static void main(String argv[]){
        JPanelParent jpp = new JPanelParent();
        jpp.setVisible(true);
        jpp.setSize(300,300);
        jpp.setBackground(Color.black);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand your question, then first before you add your `JPanels` into parent frame, you need to tell the `parent frame` to add the `component` in a specific coordinates, and could be done by set the `Layout` for the parent frame with null.

add this line at the first line in your constructor.

```
setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, But i want to set the coder red first, on top of red yellow, above that green. But it works in the reverse order.

Comment: Congrats, and please accept it as answer if that solved you problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `JLayeredPane`. See more [How to Use JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

```
public JPanelParent() throws HeadlessException {
    JPanel nPanel = getNode(10, 10, 20, 20, Color.red, 1);
    JPanel nPanel2 = getNode(20, 20, 20, 20, Color.yellow, 2);
    JPanel nPanel3 = getNode(30, 30, 20, 20, Color.green, 3);
    JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
    pane.add(nPanel, new Integer(1));
    pane.add(nPanel2, new Integer(2));
    pane.add(nPanel3, new Integer(3));

    setContentPane(pane);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Note: the `Integer` value passed is the layer order. The higher the number, the higher **on top** the layer

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPanelParent extends JFrame {

    public JPanelParent() throws HeadlessException {
        JPanel nPanel = getNode(10, 10, 20, 20, Color.red, 1);
        JPanel nPanel2 = getNode(20, 20, 20, 20, Color.yellow, 2);
        JPanel nPanel3 = getNode(30, 30, 20, 20, Color.green, 3);
        JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
        pane.add(nPanel, new Integer(1));
        pane.add(nPanel2, new Integer(2));
        pane.add(nPanel3, new Integer(3));

        setContentPane(pane);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public JPanel getNode(int i, int i1, int j, int j1, Color color, int zOrder) {
        JPanel nodePanel = new JPanel();
        nodePanel.setBackground(color);
        nodePanel.setBounds(i, i1, j, j1);
        nodePanel.setOpaque(true);
        nodePanel.setLayout(null);
        return nodePanel;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanelParent jpp = new JPanelParent();
                jpp.setVisible(true);
                jpp.setSize(300, 300);
                jpp.setBackground(Color.black);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

**Side Note**

- Swing programs should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread (as I've done in the example above). See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Looks great. Is it not possible to do the same without `jLayeredPane`?

Comment: You _can_ but a `JLayeredPane` has so many options to go with it, like changing layer positions and more. If you're really interested, you should check out the tutorials I linked. You'll learn a lot about it.

Comment: but the problem is existing code which i have to edit doesnt use `JLayeredPane`. When I try to do the same without `JLayeredPane`, it throws error

Comment: With the code in your post? .. What error? If you're talking about the `Integer` argument, its because `JLayeredPane` _has_ `add(component, Integer)`. If you just trying to use that without `JLayeredPane` it wont work, because `JFrame` doesnt have that method. When you asked if you can do it without `JLayeredPane` I thought you meant something else.

Comment: I changed the `JLayeredPane` with JPanel. Getting the below error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1080)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:460)

Comment: Yeah you can't do that. Can't specify layering positions like that with `JPanel`

Comment: This is what `JLayeredPane` is meant for.